# Adding a button element changes the position of the div it is in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic layout with 6 dynamically sized panels for content, arranged in two rows and three columns.

The panels are `<div>`'s and are set to a width of 26% with 2% margins, and `display:inline-block;`.

They are all evenly spaced and look correct, but as soon as I add a `<button>` element, the box in the 1st row, and 2nd column shifts up about 20 pixels.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Client</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/Main.css' />
    <script src="JavaScript/Main.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Main.onLoad();">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>content</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>content</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>content</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>content</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>content</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>concent</h3>
        <div class="innerContainer" id="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(227, 111, 30);
    height: 100%;
}

.innerContainer {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    clear:none;
    width: 26%;
    height: 41%;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 40px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
    background-color: white;
}

.panel h3 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
}

.panel button {
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS here so we can see what the problem is. Also a JSFiddle would be helpful as well.

Comment: You need to add `vertical-align:top` to your `.panel` class.

Comment: @Paulie_D That did the trick, thank you. I'm not too good with CSS yet :P

Comment: @Paulie_D Please post that as the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align:top`. See this fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dxGsN/1/

So your css would be:

```
.panel {
   display: inline-block;
   clear:none;
   width: 26%;
   height: 41%;
   margin: 2%;
   padding: 30px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
   -moz-border-radius: 40px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
   border-radius: 40px; /* future proofing */
   -khtml-border-radius: 40px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
   background-color: white;
   /*ADD THIS LINE*/
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

---

Or alternatively, you could use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxGsN/2/

```
display: block;
float: left;
```